# Memory leak in audio callback thread (iOS)

Tags: iphone, multithreading, memory-leaks, audiounit

My app has an audio recording callback which is called by the RemoteIO AudioUnit framework. The AudioUnit calls the callback in a thread different from the main thread, so it does not have an autorelease pool. In this callback I do the following:

- Alloc a buffer for the recorded samples.
- Call `AudioUnitRender` to fill up this buffer.
- Open a file for logging using `freopen`.
- Call an audio processing method.
- Depending on the audio, update the UI on the main thread, using `performSelectorOnMainThread` (sent to the view controller).

In addition, I have a function called `testFilter()` that does some benchmarking, which I call in the view controller's `viewDidLoad`, before the audio session is initialized, hence before the audio callback is called for the first time. In this function I allocate a buffer (using malloc/free) and call the same audio processing method I mentioned above.

Now, the problem is (on the device, not the simulator):

- If I comment out the call to `testFilter()`, I don't get any memory-leak-related messages.
- If I do call `testFilter()`, I start getting a bunch of messages from within the audio callback (The first 5 messages are my logs from the `testFilter()` method):

> 2011-01-20 23:05:10.358 TimeKeeper[389:307] initializing buffer...
>
> 2011-01-20 23:05:10.693 TimeKeeper[389:307] done...
>
> 2011-01-20 23:05:10.696 TimeKeeper[389:307] processing buffer...
>
> 2011-01-20 23:05:15.772 TimeKeeper[389:307] done...
>
> 2011-01-20 23:05:15.775 TimeKeeper[389:307] elapsed time 5.073843
>
> 2011-01-20 23:05:16.319 TimeKeeper[389:660f] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x137330 of class __NSCFData autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
>
> 2011-01-20 23:05:16.327 TimeKeeper[389:660f] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1373a0 of class __NSCFData autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

and so on. The callback has a different thread, as can be seen in the log.

How come these warnings only happen if I call a function which is called and finished before the audio session is even initialized? How can I detect the leak?

**Appendix**

The relevant methods:

```
void testFilter () {
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR == 0
    freopen([@"/tmp/console.log" cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"a",stderr);
#endif
    int bufSize = 2048;
    int numsec=100;
    OnsetDetector * onsetDetector = [[OnsetDetector alloc] init];
    AudioSampleDataType *buffer = (AudioSampleDataType*) malloc (44100*numsec * sizeof(AudioSampleDataType)); // numsec seconds of audio @44100

    AudioBufferList bufferList;
    bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
    bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData = buffer;
    bufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = sizeof (AudioSampleDataType) * bufSize;
    bufferList.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1; 

    //--- init buffer
    NSLog(@"\n\n---***---***---");
    NSLog(@"initializing buffer...");
    for (int i = 0; i < 44100*numsec; ++i) {
        *(buffer+i) = (AudioSampleDataType)rand();
    }
    NSLog(@"done...");

    NSLog(@"processing buffer...");
    CFAbsoluteTime t0 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    for (int i = 0; (i+1)*bufSize < 44100*numsec; ++i) {
        bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData = buffer + i * bufSize;
        [onsetDetector process:&bufferList];
    }   
    CFAbsoluteTime t1 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    NSLog(@"done...");
    NSLog(@"elapsed time %1.6f",(double)(t1-t0));
    free(buffer);
    [onsetDetector release];
}
```

And:

```
OSStatus recordingCallback (void *inRefCon, 
                            AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, 
                            const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, 
                            UInt32 inBusNumber, 
                            UInt32 inNumberFrames, 
                            AudioBufferList *ioData) {

    AudioBufferList bufferList;

    // redundant
    SInt16 *buffer = (SInt16 *)malloc (sizeof (AudioSampleDataType) * inNumberFrames);
    bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
    bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData = buffer;
    bufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = sizeof (AudioSampleDataType) * inNumberFrames;
    bufferList.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;

    ioData = &bufferList;

    // Obtain recorded samples  
    OSStatus status;

    MainViewController  *mainViewController = (MainViewController *)inRefCon;
    AudioManager        *audioManager       = [mainViewController audioManager];
    SampleManager       *sampleManager      = [audioManager sampleManager];

    status = AudioUnitRender([audioManager audioUnit], 
                             ioActionFlags, 
                             inTimeStamp, 
                             inBusNumber, //1
                             inNumberFrames, 
                             ioData);

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR == 0
    freopen([@"/tmp/console.log" cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"a",stdout);
#endif

    // send to onset detector
    SInt32 onset = [[audioManager onsetDetector] process:ioData];
    if (onset > 0) {
        NSLog(@"onset - %ld\n", sampleManager.recCnt + onset);

        //--- updating the UI - must be done on main thread
        [mainViewController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(tapButtonPressed) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        [mainViewController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(onsetLedOn) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    }

    sampleManager.recCnt += inNumberFrames; 

    free(buffer);
    return noErr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the problem was caused by `freopen` not followed by `fclose`. I am passing `stderr` as a 3rd argument to `freopen`, so the log messages are redirected to a file. If I call `fclose` at the end of the callback, no memory-leak errors appear.

Some questions still need an answer though:

- Why using `autorelease` pool did not solve the problem? I guess it is because `freopen` is a `C` function, so no autorelease messages are sent anyway.
- The only situation in which the error messages are thrown is:

  - `freopen` is used in a function on the main thread, without `fclose`
  - `freopen` is used in an audio callback on a different thread, without `fclose`.

That is, if `freopen` is used only in the audio callback thread (and not on the main thread), no errors appear.

**Edit**

Another weird behavior is that even if do use `fclose` in both threads, but I pass `stdout` on the main thread and `stderr` in the audio callback thread, I get the error messages. I think it's got something to do with the way `NSLog` is called when there is more then one thread. Any insights on this are welcomed.

Comment: My final conclusion from all this headache is not using `freopen` and `NSLog` at all, but to implement my own logging class which will use file output (C's `fprintf` or some Cocoa file IO class)

Answer (score 2):

The "just leaking" error message is what you get where your method (or some other method your method calls) tries to `autorelease` an object when there is no autorelease pool in place. Without a pool, there is nothing to keep track of which objects need releasing, and therefore they just leak.

On the main thread, such a pool is automatically created and managed for you, but on secondary threads you have to do it yourself.

What you need to do is alter your functions to allocate a pool:

```
void myFunction() {
   NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];  

   // do stuff here

   [pool release];
}
```

And this will make the error messages go away, and fix the leaks.

Comment: Thank you. I know about the autorelease pool and I know it would make to error messages go away, but I fail to understand two things: 1. What object is being tried to autorelease, and 2. Why these messages appear only if I call a function on the main thread, even before the audio thread is created.

Comment: ** Update ** Even if I put all the callback commands inside an autorelease pool (and call [pool drain] at the end), the error messages still occurring. Any other ideas?